# PDF table to pandas data frame using camelot

Tags: python, pandas, python-camelot

I'm trying to create a simple way to get data from pdf into a pandas data frame. Something like that:

```py
import camelot
import pandas as pd

pdf = camelot.read_pdf("file1.pdf")

print(pdf[0].df)
```

The point is that I'm trying with two different files: [File 1](https://examedeordem.oab.org.br/pdf/2012.1%20-%20VII%20EOU%20-%20Desempenho%20por%20IES%20e%20Campus.pdf) and [File 2](https://examedeordem.oab.org.br/pdf/2020.1%20%E2%80%93%20XXXI%20EOU%20%E2%80%93%20Desempenho%20por%20IES%20e%20Campus.pdf) but for the second file I'm not able to get the info. It has more columns but I believe it shouldn't be a problem.

Also, the only way I could get a table from file 2 was using `flavor="stream"`

Result for [File 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j50l.png)

Result for [File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxLek.png)

Comment: If my answer is useful, please accept and/or upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly extract tables from the second file, it is necessary to process background lines, [using the appropriate parameter (process_background)](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#process-background-lines) for lattice method, as you can see in the following code:

```
import camelot

tables=camelot.read_pdf('file2.pdf', process_background=True)

for table in tables:
    print(table.df)
```

Comment: That's what I need. I didn't know such a parameter. Thanks for the help. It was very useful.